# Do I need Read-Write lock here

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I have writing a multi threaded code. I am not sure, whether I would need a read and write lock mechanism. Could you please go through the usecase and tell me do I have to use read-write lock or just normal mutex will do.

Use case:
1) Class having two variables. These are accessed by every thread before doing operation.
2) When something goes wrong, these variables are updated to reflect the error scenarios.
Thus threads reading these variables can take different decisions (including abort)

Here, in second point, I need to update the data. And in first point, every thread will use the data. So, my question is do I have to use write lock while updating data and read lock while reading the data. (Note: Both variables are in memory. Just a boolean flag & string)

I am confused because as my both vars are in memory. So does OS take care when integrity. I mean I can live with 1 or 2 threads missing the updated value when some thread is writing the data in mutex.

Please tell if I am right or wrong? Also please tell If I have to use read-write lock or just normal mutex would do.

**Update:** I am sorry that I did not give platform and compiler name. I am on RHEL 5.0 and using gcc 4.6. My platform is x86_64. But I don not want my code to be OS specific because we are going to port the code shortly to Solaris 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, ignore those other answerers talking about volatile. [Volatile is almost useless for multithreaded programming](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/), and any false sense of safety given by it is just that - false.

Now, whether you need a lock depends on what you're doing with these variables. You will need a *memory barrier* at least (locks imply one).

So let's give an example:

- One flag is an error flag. If zero, you continue, otherwise, you abort.
- Another flag is a diagnostic code flag. It gives the precise reason for the error.

In this case, one option would be to do the following:

- Read the error flag without a lock, but with read memory barriers after the read.
- When an error occurs, take a lock, set the diagnostic code and error flags, then release the lock. If the diagnostic code is already set, release the lock immediately.

The memory barriers are needed, as otherwise the compiler (or CPU!) may choose to cache the same result for every read.

Of course, if the semantics of your two variables are different, the answer may vary. You'll need to be more specific.

Note that the exact mechanism for specifying locks and memory barriers depends on the compiler. C++0x provides a portable mechanism, but few compilers fully implement the C++0x standard yet. Please specify your compiler and OS for a more detailed answer.

As for your output data, you will almost certainly need a lock there. Try to avoid taking these locks too often though, as too much lock contention will kill your performance.

Comment: Note that on MSVC, [`volatile` does introduce acquire/release semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx).  Not portable, of course, but neither are memory barriers in general prior to C++0x :-)

Comment: I believe because of the strong cache-coherency memory model implemented on the x86/x86_64 platform, a memory barrier operation would not be needed ... once one thread stores a new value in the given variables, the processor executing the write will automatically invalidate the cache-lines sharing that variable in the other processors.

Comment: @bdonlan, why do you need barriers around reading the error flag? A read acquire barrier after reading the error flag (if it's set) should be sufficient unless you are running on a DEC Alpha (which required an `isync` instead). Assuming you use a write release barrier before setting the error flag.

Comment: @Nemo and @Jason, the OP did not specify they were using MSVC, or that they were using x86. @MSN: I didn't want the read to occur early, although I suppose in this specific case it doesn't hurt...

Comment: @bdonlan ... I completely understand your reasoning, but I just wanted to point out for anyone reading the post that a lot of this is platform-specific.  For instance, introducing memory barriers on x86, when they aren't needed, can cause significant performance penalties, since they end up being full-fence instructions (x86 doesn't have separate instructions for acquire/release semantics like Itanium does ... x86 assembly instructions like SFENCE and LFENCE are not acquire/release semantics).  On other platforms with weak cache-consistency models, your suggestions are an absolute must.

Comment: There are a number of variants of memory barriers; rather than using a full barrier, one can use a barrier primitive that compiles to nothing when compiled for x86, for example (the Linux kernel does this sort of thing a lot).

Comment: My own point is that "volatile is almost useless for multithreaded programming" is too strong of a statement, since it is not true for Microsoft's compilers, which do insert memory barriers for "volatile" loads and stores.  The right answer is "use C++0x or specify your compiler and OS" as you said later; generalizations on this topic (including "volatile is useless") are usually wrong.

Comment: @Nemo, I still hold that volatile is a bad idea even in MSVC. It allows your code to work on MSVC, perhaps, but if later you want to port your code, you can potentially have code that will compile, but is broken nevertheless. Using built-in barrier directives both makes your intentions clear, but also ensures that your code will fail safe on alternate platforms. It's not any more difficult, either, so you have no excuse :)

Comment: @bdolan: What do you mean by "Read the error flag without a lock, but with read memory barriers after the read."

So in short, I will have to use read & write lock for my usecase right? Or do you need more data to determine the same.

Comment: @Amey, the protocol I specified was for the specific combination of variables I made up (since you did not provide details). Read barriers are not a lock; on GCC you can issue a full memory barrier with `__sync_synchronize()` (on some non-x86 hardware, there may be faster operations than a full memory barrier, but that's an inline asm bridge you can cross when the time comes). It would be best to describe in more detail what those 'two variables' do, though.

Answer (score 0):

If they are atomic variables (C1x `stdatomic.h` or C++0x `atomic`), then you don't need read/write locks.  With earlier C/C++ standards, there's no portable way of using multiple threads at all, so you need to look into how the implementation you are using does things.  In most implementations, data types that can be accessed with a single machine instruction are atomic.

Note that just having an atomic variable is not enough -- you probably also need to declare it as `volatile` to guarantee that the compiler does not do things that will cause you to miss updates from other threads.

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/ - volatile is a BAD idea. And std::atomic already has the necessary barriers built in. And, depending on what you're doing with the variables, you may indeed need locks. So, bad advice all around.

Comment: `volatile` only prevents compiler re-ordering of operations within a given thread.  That's useful for some things, such as MMIO (memory-mapped I/O), but for controlling the visibility of reads and writes among multiple threads, `volatile` doesn't help except in certain platform-specific instances (i.e., MSVC).

Comment: @bdonian: `stdatomic.h` does not have barriers to prevent caching without other memory accesses, so volatile may be needed depending on how you use it -- in particular you can't spin on reading a `stdatomic` in isolation to anything else; you need to add `volatile` in that case.  You should READ the blog you posted a link to and actually understand what it is saying...

Comment: @Jason: which is why I said that you need to check the documentation for your implementation to see what it does -- `volatile` is useful on some implementations and useless on others.

Answer (score -1):

> Thus threads reading these variables can take different decisions (including abort)

So each thread need to ensure that it reads the updated data. Also since the variables are shared, you need to take care about the race condition as well.

So in short - you **need** to use read/write locks when reading and writing to these shared variables.

See if you can use volatile variables - that should save you from using locks when you read the values (however write should still be with locks). This is applicable only because you said that -

> I mean I can live with 1 or 2 threads missing the updated value when some thread is writing the data in mutex

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/ - volatile is a BAD idea. Use proper memory barriers instead.

Comment: @bdonlan: Volatile, as I understand, ensures memory visibility across threads. I am no where saying that it should be used for synchronization.

Comment: volatile does not, in fact, ensure memory visibility across threads. The CPU and compiler is free to delay your volatile write indefinitely, as long as it is ordered with respect to other volatile accesses on the same CPU. Volatile makes no ordering guarantees with respect to other threads whatsoever.